# Bootstrap top navbar - how to add one element in the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my ASP.NET 5 web app in Visual Studio 2015, the default _Layout.cshtml view (also shown in [MSDN tutorial here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bootstrap.html)) is using the following css section for top navbar that displays Home, About, Contact links on the left and LoginName on the righ. How can I add some text, say, "My Company Name" in the center of the navbar. I tried `<p class="navbar-brand center-block">My Company Name</p>` and `<p class="navbar-brand style=text-align:center;">My Company Name</p>` But still "My Company Name" is displayed on the left:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">App Name</a>               
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="navbar-brand center-block">My Company Name</p>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">App Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/87O7iyygPy

EDIT: updated code example and the bootply too.

Comment: Thank you for helping (+1 for it). Your solution also works but I was a bit hesitant modifying a Bootstrap class.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with modifying classes like navbar-brand, as you are changing its position (over riding the default float etc). But I wouldn't recommend changing things like container, row, and the col-* classes :)

Comment: One issue I see modifying the Bootstrap `.navbar-brand` class is that the other elements using this class also end up in the center. For example in my original post, `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">App Name</a>` and `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
` now overlap in the center.

Comment: But you wouldn't have two navbar-brand's, you would have one, and two (or however many) child elements... :) .navbar-brand being the structural element (much like .col-* etc)

Comment: Please pardon me for lack of in-depth knowledge of CSS. In the HTML posted in my original post above, I'm using navbar-brand at two places one for `App Name` and the other for `My Company Name`; so, how do I change the class attribute there to make it work?

Comment: I've edited my answer to highlight what (in my opinion) you should change.

Comment: Oops, I've misread your actual intentions - having App Name on the left, and Company Name on the right.... Keep the .navbar-brand center, and use your existing left aligned navbar to hold the App Name - in the first `li`.  -- Edited my answer (and the bootply) to reflect this.

Comment: For me the solution was to move the `App Name` to the first `<li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">TaxAct</a></li>` and create a different class, say, 'brand` (as suggested by `BviLLe_Kid`) with the attributes you define in your modified `navbar-brand` class. I'm using mix of suggestions from both of you, but since you replied first, I'm marking your response as an `answer`. Thank you both for helping.

Comment: Glad you have a solution, that's the main thing. I did indeed edit my answer earlier to reflect my comments. I also upvoted BviLLe's answer.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

Here is my updated answer to make your `My Company Name` and `App Name` both links:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">App Name</a>
          <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" class="navbar-brand brand">
            <div class="brand-inner">My Company Name</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;   
}

.brand-inner{
    left:-50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/l116cll2on)

Comment: I created a new `class` brand in wwwroot\css\site.css file in my Visual Studio 2015 project and it works. But now, the link `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">App Name</a>` does not work, How can we make this link work?

Comment: @nam are you able to use razor syntax?

Comment: does it appear like a link? what happens when you click it?

Comment: It does not appear like a link. Following is also happening: When I hover over `App Name`, the `My Company Name` becomes an active link. On the other hand, when I hover over the other links `Home`, `About`, `Contact` these links, as expected, become active link. So the issue is only with the `App Name` link.

Comment: I took out the part of my solution that included the `<p class="navbar-brand center-block">My Company Name</p>`.. see my edited solution and try that

Comment: But I need to keep the `App Name` on the top left and add `My Company Name` in the center of the navbar. Using your original solution I'm able to add the `My Company Name` in the center but the `App Name`  link stops working.

Comment: Ok can you create a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) and post it as a comment with what you currently have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108849/discussion-between-nam-and-bville-kid).

Comment: Per your suggestion, I've added a bootply.

Comment: @nam can you send me the link to it?

Comment: @BBviLLe_Kid. I just created a free account. I don't know how it works but [here](http://www.bootply.com/namwam/otPoTzguaM) is the link. It comes out blank when I use it. Maybe, you can help.

Comment: @nam I am working on it now.. you want both to be links or just 1 or the other? if they are going to be links to the same place then I would just do 1

Comment: I would need both: `App Name` on left and `Company Name` in the center.

Comment: As you can see in your own bootply demo `App Name` is still not showing as a link and when you hover over it the `My Company Name` gets highlighted as active link. Please see my last response to @Stuart where I've acknowledged using mix of suggestions from you and from @Stuart to come up with a solution. +1 for helping me.

Comment: @nam the bootply that I posted in my update for some reason did not update.. I just added the correct bootply.. please see.

Comment: Your updated bootply works. I still prefer your original solution. The issue of `App Name` link not working with that solution was resolved by moving the `App Name` tag to first `<li>`. By default, the VS2015 ASP.NET 5 template creates the `App Name` tag right below the `<\button>` tag where, for some reason, the link after your original solution was not working. I still adopted your idea of creating a separate class `.brand` rather than modifying a built-in bootstrap class.